How to get all solutions of a nonlinear system equations
I am trying to obtain the steady state points of the following ODE system for a SIR model (steady state points are the solutions when the equations of the system equal zero):
import sympy as sp
S, I, R, b, g = sp.symbols('S I R b g')
dSdt = -b * S * I
dIdt = b * S * I - g * I
dRdt = g * I
steady_states = sp.solve([dSdt, dIdt, dRdt], [S, I, R])
steady_states

When I set numerical values for b and g, it shows all solutions, but when I leave them as symbols, it only shows this solution:
[(S,0,R)]

the other solution should be:
[(g/b,0,R)]

is it possible to get both of them ? Perhaps another function in sympy? Thanks in advance.

The meaning of that solution is that you can choose anything for S and R if I = 0.

Ohh I see, thank you very much. My bad not interpreting that. T_T

The solution of S = g/b would be redundant since the only way to make the equations 0 with I is when I=0 (since it is the only factor that can make the last equation zero). And with I=0 it doesn't matter what S is. If you want to see what the individual solutions of each equation are, solve them individually for each variable:
>>> ...
>>> e,v=([dSdt, dIdt, dRdt], [S, I, R])
>>> [{vi:(solve(ei,vi) or [vi])[0] for vi in v} for ei in e]
[{S: 0, I: 0, R: R}, {S: g/b, I: 0, R: R}, {S: S, I: 0, R: R}]

